# How to get a frequency of the elements in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and struggling a little in manipulating lists. I have a list which roughly looks like this

```
rows = [[u'12'], [u'12'], [u'12'], [u'12'], [u'13'], [u'13'], [u'14'], [u'14'], [u'14']]
```

. I want to get the count of each of these elements. I would like the result to look like this

```
res = [[12,4], [13,2], [14,3]]
```

How do I do this? I tried

```
collections.Counter(rows)
```

but it gave me

```
TypeError: Unhashable type 'list'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the sublists always have just one item?

```
>>> rows = [[u'12'],[u'12'],[u'12'],[u'12'],[u'13'],[u'13'],[u'14'],[u'14'],[u'14']]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [[int(k), v] for k, v in Counter(i[0] for i in rows).items()]
[[13, 2], [12, 4], [14, 3]]
```

If the sublists can have more than one item

```
>>> [[int(k), v] for k, v in Counter(j for i in rows for j in i).items()]
[[13, 2], [12, 4], [14, 3]]
```

You can throw `sorted` into the mix like this, if the order is important

```
>>> sorted([int(k), v] for k, v in Counter(i[0] for i in rows).items())
[[12, 4], [13, 2], [14, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` is the way to go. But you are actually passing the list of lists as it is. You actually need to flatten the list of lists and then pass it to `Counter`.

```
rows = [[u'12'],[u'12'],[u'12'],[u'12'],[u'13'],[u'13'],[u'14'],[u'14'],[u'14']]
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
res = sorted(Counter(int(item) for item in chain.from_iterable(rows)).items())
print res
```

**Output**

```
[(12, 4), (13, 2), (14, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error `TypeError: Unhashable type 'list'` is because you are trying to make the list as the key for the dictionary which is not allowed because list is a mutable object. Mutable objects are not allowed to be keys since they can change. You have couple of options for your issue above. Either you can turn your list into a tuple which is immutable object or since it looks like your lists contain just one element, you can just get the first element. Here is an implementation of that below:

```
rows = [[u'12'], [u'12'], [u'12'], [u'12'], [u'13'], [u'13'], [u'14'], [u'14'], [u'14']]
count_dict = {}
for row in rows:
    key = row[0]
    if key in count_dict:
        count_dict[key] += 1
    else:
        count_dict[key] = 1 

print count_dict
```

> That will get you `{u'13': 2, u'12': 4, u'14': 3}`